# Unable to filter tableview created using array of dictionary

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, filter, uisearchcontroller

I am new to swift and Xcode and I have been progressing along with an app that has tableview (of employees with first name space last name) created using a plist dictionary used as NSarray. I am trying to add a search feature.

Here is my code:

var employeeSearch = Array>()

```
let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)

func getSwiftArrayFromPlist() -> (Array<Dictionary<String,String>>) {

    let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Sheet1", ofType: "plist")
    var arr: NSArray?
    arr = NSArray(contentsOfFile: path!)
    return (arr as? Array<Dictionary<String,String>>)!
}


func searchBarIsEmpty() -> Bool {
    // Returns true if the text is empty or nil
    return searchController.searchBar.text?.isEmpty ?? true
}
```

// no errors in above  function

// I am getting a number of errors in the function below

```
func searchBar(searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
    employeeSearch = getSwiftArrayFromPlist().filter { $0["lastname".lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased()]}
    print(employeeSearch)
    searchActive = !employeeSearch.isEmpty
    tblData.reloadData()
}
//getting many errors in above attempt to get a filtered array of dictionary to reload data in tableview
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

//Mar 1 - Finally this worked, but only equals condition was going without errors. My expectation was to have contains feature.. 
    func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {

```
    if searchBar.text == nil || searchBar.text == "" {
        isSearching = false
        view.endEditing(true)
        employee1View.reloadData()
    } else {
        isSearching = true
        employeeSearch = getSwiftArrayFromPlist()

        currentEmployeeSearch = employeeSearch.filter {($0["lastname"]?.lowercased() == searchText.lowercased())}
        //currentEmployeeSearch = employeeSearch.filter {($0["lastname"]?.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased())}
        employee1View.reloadData()
    }
}
```

// *****************************************

Comment: Note: the var declaration shows incorrectly in this post. it s var employeeSearch = Array<Dictionary<String,String>>()

Comment: I moved my comment to an answer for readability.

Comment: Not related but why do you recreate the array from disk in each call of `textDidChange`? That unnecessarily expensive. And it's highly recommended to use `PropertyListSerialization` or even `PropertyListDecoder` rather the `NSArray` convenience API

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Steve's solution worked. Thank you very much!
//**********************
func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {

```
    if searchBar.text == nil || searchBar.text == "" {
        isSearching = false
        view.endEditing(true)
        employee1View.reloadData()
    } else {
        isSearching = true
        employeeSearch = getSwiftArrayFromPlist()

        //currentEmployeeSearch = employeeSearch.filter {($0["lastname"]?.lowercased() == searchText.lowercased())}
        currentEmployeeSearch = employeeSearch.filter {($0["lastname"]?.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased())) ?? false}
        employee1View.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that the filter has incorrect brackets. I believe

```
employeeSearch = getSwiftArrayFromPlist().filter { $0["lastname".lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased()]}
```

should be

```
employeeSearch = getSwiftArrayFromPlist().filter { $0["lastname"].lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased())}
```

Updated answer to help with handling optionals

```
func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
    employeeSearch = getSwiftArrayFromPlist()

    guard !searchText.isEmpty else {
        // In here set the array used in the rest of the app equal to employeeSearch
        return employeeSearch
    }

    currentEmployeeSearch = employeeSearch.filter{
        guard let lowerCasedLastName = $0["lastname"].lowercased() else {
            //If we didn't get a lowercased last name from the employeeSearchArray we return false
            // false means we don't want to include that in the search results array
            return false }
        //If we do have a lowerCasedLastName lets see if it contains the search text
        return lowerCasedLastName.contains(searchText.lowercased())
    }

    employee1View.reloadData()

    //Note: Depending on what array the rest of your application uses you will want to set it equal to the value returned from the filter or returned from the else block of the guard against searchText being empty.
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I pasted your suggestion. It complained two more times, but they were issues with not having ! sign. Now the compiler calmed down after yelling at me for the last two day with this line:

Comment: employeeSearch = getSwiftArrayFromPlist().filter { ($0["lastname"]?.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased()))!}

Comment: @Vadian thank you for your suggestion for efficiency. I will certainly get to it next. It has been a bloodbath for the last two days with just a single line in function getting an array of dictionary to filter. Phew!

Comment: Glad to hear you figured it out. I suggest using protections if let or something to avoid force unwrapping. Just in case the search returns nil (which can happen) the for unwrap will crash your application.

Comment: Steve, Sorry I need help again. I tried to protect with if let statement, but I get more errors (too many to list). Here is the code

Comment: if let employeeSearch = getSwiftArrayFromPlist().filter {$0["lastname".lowercased(), String.lowercased(searchText)?].contains(searchText.lowercased()}
            
            {return getSwiftArrayFromPlist()["lastname"]: value(forKey: "lastname"?).contains(searchText.lowercase()
                    } else
                {
                return getSwiftArrayFromPlist()
                    }
                
             employee1View.reloadData()
                
                
                
                print(employeeSearch)
                return true
        }

Comment: My goal is to get a filtered table view for the search criteria that contains  searched last names. If not, just go back to the existing array, which is in the format Array<Dictionary<String, String>

Comment: You should look up if let to get an understanding of what it’s doing. But essentially it’s a way to unwrap an optional and it puts you into the block if the variable you’re attempting to access is not nil. In your case above you have brackets that are misaligned. Most notably $0[“lastname”] would be the way to get the value for the key last name. What you have is trying to check if the word  value for the key of the result of if lastname contains the search text so it’s essentially doing $0[true/false]. Once you sort out your brackets you can work on the force unwraps more easily.

Comment: Thanks Steve. I will review the if let concept again. It has been days since I am trying to get past this..

Comment: Can you show me what the line that compiled looked like before you attempted using if let?

Comment: I have been working on this. After several tweaks here is the filter condition I got to without errors. Being a void function, swift doesn't like return value, but I don't want to mess with seeded function of swift and add return clause in function header.

Comment: func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
        
        employeeSearch = getSwiftArrayFromPlist()
        currentEmployeeSearch = employeeSearch.filter{ ($0["lastname".lowercased()]?.contains(searchText.lowercased()))! }
            
                if searchText.isEmpty {
                    return employeeSearch
                }
                else {
                  return currentEmployeeSearch
            }
        
        employee1View.reloadData()
    }

Comment: Being new to stack overflow, I am pasting the code as response to answers, but the code is not indented properly and not readable. If there is a better way, please let me know.

Comment: I’m unaware of a better way unless you were to edit the original question. It’s fine though I can copy the code and format it on my side. I’ll try to find time tomorrow to take a look.

Comment: I've updated my answer to show an example of how to handle optionals. Hopefully it helps.

Comment: Steve, I am working on this. The guard !searchText.IsEmpty has a statement "return employeeSearch", but this gives an error since the function its void. So I kept return, and commented out employeeSearch. The error was fixed. But the employee1.reloadData() seems to ignore the filtered output. BTW, the return output "lowerCasedLastName.contains(searchText.lowercased())" picks every last name regardless of the search letter.

Comment: I can’t help much with employee1 reload data as I don’t know what data it’s looking at. As long as you update the data properly before calling reload it should function. As far as the contains check it should be working. I’d suggest opening up a playground and trying a sample of that contains check to see what the problem might be.

Comment: Thanks a lot Steve for your time and guidance. I have made progress. The count function was the culprit. I fixed it. Now the filter works, but it is not refreshing the tableview. Working on this... thanks again for your guidance. It was very helpful.

Comment: Finally I got it to work, but with equals conditions instead of "contains". That continues to be an issue. Any thoughts on this greatly appreciated! - Dharma

Comment: Equals sounds strange to use. Can you explain what you type in the search and what results you expect to get? Example being. If I have last names: `one, two, three` and I search for `o` and use contains I will get back `one, two`, because both of them contain o's while `three` does not. If you used equals you'd get nothing back.

Comment: The table View shows first name space last name. Actually my goal was to show search results as the user started typing letters (first or last). So I started with last name with a hope to add first name later. But I am stuck at (.contains) condition due to several errors. My solution is not elegant. I have posted by edited code

Comment: Three messages. "Expected ',' separator. Fix - insert ','. Next one  "Value of options; type 'Bool?' not unwrapped. Did you mean to use '!' or '?' . Third message is "Expected expression in list of expressions". If I start taking these fixes, it pops up more and more messages. Thank you

Comment: You could try to put ‘?? False’ after the contains check. Essentially what it’s saying is that you need to return a bool in the filter call not an optional bool. The ‘?? False’ would say return false if the lastname string returned nil.

Comment: Wow! That was a tranquilizer! Finally the compiler calmed down. It works as expected!!! Hats off to you Steve! Thanks for your patience and staying with me. I am learning this. People like you motivate me not to give up. I owe you a lunch!

Comment: Glad it helped, it takes some time to get a grasp of a new language take your time and you'll get there.